# asp.net minified css files in fonts- and images folder

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, .net-core, minify

I'm experiencing something (that i think is) very weird.

I'm running an ASP.net application, and I have no problems on the development build, but on the production build when minifying, the files are not found. When inspection the application in the browser, the two files not found, site.min.css and bootstrap.min.css, are residing in the Images- and the Fonts-folder respectively.

Please see screenshot below
[image]

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
    {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  },
]
```

And when included in the _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />

</environment>
```

And folder structure:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.